# Invisible 0131 number in bash

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I am trying to gather number from file using bash. My file looks like this:

```
number = 123;
```

I use following command to get it:

```
grep number file.txt | tr -dc 0-9
```

And what I get is:

```
0131123
```

I tried different number and different methods `sed 's/[^0-9]//g'` but it always gives me result 0131+my_number. 
Any ideas why?

**UPDATE**

Giving answers to your questions

```
user@domain:/tmp$ grep number file.txt
number = 123;
user@domain:/tmp$ grep number file.txt | tr -dc 0-9
0131123user@domain:/tmp$ 
user@domain:/tmp$ grep number file.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
0131123
user@domain:/tmp$ cat file.txt 
number = 123;
```

As you can see file doesn't contain anything except one line.

**UPDATE 2**

Results of commands given by [antak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036728/antak) and [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson)

```
user@domain:/tmp$ grep number file.txt | cat -v
^[[01;31m^[[Knumber^[[m^[[K = 123;
user@domain:/tmp$ hexdump -C file.txt
00000000  6e 75 6d 62 65 72 20 3d  20 31 32 33 3b 0a        |number = 123;.|
0000000e
```

After `cat -v` I can see magic 0131, but I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Does `file.txt` have any other line containing `number`?

Comment: Nope. Number is unique in this file.

Comment: When I try this, I get '123', as one would expect. I don't see why you get this problem... I suspect the '0131' prefix is produced by another part of your script.

Comment: I had the same result as @roky. What happens if you do just the first part: `grep number file.txt`?

Comment: What is the *complete contents* of file.txt? I bet you have more lines with digits 0, 1, 3 and 1 somewhere before that "number =" line.

Comment: Try `grep number file.txt | cat -v` -- that'll show any normally-invisible characters in the file.

Comment: What does `hexdump -C file.txt` show?

Comment: Or `sed -n 's/^number *= *//p' file.txt`

Comment: Those are ANSI or VT100 escape sequences.  You probably created the file with something like `cat > file.txt` and tried to use cursor keys to edit while you were typing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/number = \(.*\);/\1/p' file.txt
```

or with grep and friends:

```
grep number file.txt | cut -d' ' -f3 | tr -d ';'
```

or (as you suggested) :

```
grep number file.txt | tr -dc 0-9
```

Update: I didn't tried your example before giving the original answer. Just wanted to say that your example worked for me.. (you see above)

Comment: Also with `grep`, this one also works: `grep -Po '(?<=)\d+' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui Nice one! :)

Comment: @fedorqui No it doesn't with most greps, since these are perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It's from your `grep --colour=always` setting. When it's set, it will color the matching substring with red color by default (see detail [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html)), which will save as `^[[01;31m^[[K....^[[m^[[K` tag, where the ... is the matched substring. Turn off the `--colour` option or change to use `--colour=auto`, you will solve the problem.

btw, I think I deserve an up-vote for the answer :)

Comment: Why color? I don't see anything mentioning color in the original question.

Comment: because by default `GREP_COLOR` is set as `mt=1;31` (which is bold red color) for any matching substring (see detail [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html)). I guess the original poster might have set `grep --color=always` so that it will hide the color code in the grep output (which is displayed as red, but shown as `^[[01;31m^[[Knumber^[[m^[[K` in his case via `cat -v`).

Comment: Begging for karma/votes is bad form. (You _do_ have my upvote, though -- this is a good answer).

Comment: Thanks. This is my first reputation gained here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general solution which works with numbers and other data as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME='file.txt'
SEARCH_PATTERN='number'

foundLine=$(grep -m 1 "$SEARCH_PATTERN" "$FILENAME")
if [[ $foundLine =~ =.*\; ]]; then
    value=$BASH_REMATCH
    value=$(echo "${value:1:-1}" | xargs) # remove = and ; and then trim
    echo "Your value is: _${value}_"
else
    echo 'Line not found :('
fi
```

This is very useful because on a file with this content:

```
    number       =        'complex thing :3' ; # my comment with numbers 123 512
number = 'sadfhsah';
```

it must return

```
Your value is: _complex thing :3_
```

So it does not depend on numbers in comments and other garbage.

P.S. Please note that it will not work with variables that have newlines in them and with comments containing ';' characters